# Prove that $|x^3|$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to do it with the epsilon-delta definition.
So for $\forall x\in D(f)$ and $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta>0$ $\forall y$ such $|y-x|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.
Let $|y-x|<\delta$ , and $|y^3-x^3|=|y-x||y^2+yx+x^2|\leq|y-x||y+x|^2$
$\implies \delta|y-x|^2 =\epsilon$, and here im stuck.

Comment: $|x^2+xy+y^2| \le |x+y|^2$ is not true in general

Comment: Hint: the concatenation of continuous functions is continuous. Your function is the concatenation of which two functions?

Comment: $x^2$ and $|x|$?

Comment: Hint: You define $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=|x|$ that are continuous. Then $g(f(x))=$?

Comment: Ohhh I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $g(x) = x^{3}$ is continuous. Let us show that the function $f(x) = |x|$ is continuous at an arbitrary point $a \in \mathbb{R}$. To do this, let $\delta = \epsilon$ and suppose $|x-a| \le \epsilon$. Then, because of the triangle inequality, we have: $$||x|-|a||\le |x-a|\le \epsilon$$
Which proves $f$ is continuous at $a$. Now, we know that the composite of continuous functions is continuous, so if $h(x) = |x^{3}|$ then: $$h(x) = (f\circ g)(x)$$